# how can I insert a character at a certain position in a csv line

Tags: bash, csv

How should I go about inserting a character at a certain point in a csv line? For instance, if I had the following:

`1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

How could I insert `,,,,,` at the spot where the 5 (fifth field) is, so it would look like

`1,2,3,4,,,,,,5,6,7`

I found a link for how to do this for java, but unfortunately I did not have much luck finding out how to do it with bash. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk` to change a specific field:

```
awk -F"," '{OFS=","; a=$5; $5=",,,,,",a; print $0}' file
```

The idea is to update the field 5 with the desired values and then print the whole line.

---

```
 echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" | awk -F"," '{a=$5; $5=",,,,,"a; OFS=","; print}'
```

would print:

```
1,2,3,4,,,,,,5,6,7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$5=",,,,,"$5;print}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> echo "1,2,3,4,5,6" | awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}{$5=",,,,,"$5;print}'
1,2,3,4,,,,,,5,6
>
```

or you can do it using perl:

```
> echo "1,2,3,4,5,6" | perl -F, -lane '$F[4]=~s/^/,,,,,/g;print join(",",@F)'
1,2,3,4,,,,,,5,6
>
```